# Can you refer to the element on which a handler called a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I usually never use this programming style, but thought I would give it a try just so I know whats up with it.

Here is my input tag HTML:
`<input id="Read" type="checkbox" onclick="readClicked()" checked>`

And my associated function:

```
function readClicked() {
    console.log(this);
    console.log($(this));
    alert('Read Clicked!');
}
```

Is there anyway to refer to the element in which the handler that called readClicked() was called from inside the function?
Something like:

```
function readClicked() {
    var caller = function.caller;
    var type = $(caller).attr('type');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass `this` as a parameter:

```
onclick="readClicked(this);"
```

Then your function would be:

```
function readClicked(el) {
    var type = $(el).attr('type');
}
```

Although, since you're using jQuery, I would suggest binding the event with jQuery, instead of inline. Like this:

```
$("#Read, #OtherElement").on("click", clickHandler);

function clickHandler() {
    var type = $(this).attr("type");
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/mWLTw/

Answer (score 3):

```
<input id="Read" type="checkbox" onclick="readClicked(this)" checked>

function readClicked(elem) {
    console.log(elem);
    console.log($(elem));
    alert('Read Clicked!');
}
```